# How to lookup a sub-array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I tried to use aggregate and lookup but look like I cannot keep `role` in the `members` item. Any idea how to resolve it?

```
db.groups.insertMany([
    {
        title: 'Hi',
        members: [
            {
                userId: ObjectId('62589515f239750e7e44b958'), 
                role: 'Admin'
            },
            {
                userId: ObjectId('655f634c632d0c23b9d455de'), 
                role: 'Member'
            }
        ]
    }
])
```

and

```
db.users.insertMany([
    {
        _id: ObjectId('62589515f239750e7e44b958'), 
        name: 'A',
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('655f634c632d0c23b9d455de'), 
        name: 'B',
    }
])
```

How do we can have a result like this by using aggregate, many thanks:

```
{
    title: 'Hi',
    members: [
        {
            user: {
                _id: ObjectId('62589515f239750e7e44b958'), 
                name: 'A',
            },
            role: 'Admin'
        },
        {
            user: {
                _id: ObjectId('655f634c632d0c23b9d455de'), 
                name: 'B',
            },
            role: 'Member'
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$unwind` the members and perform `$lookup`. Wrangle the object a bit and `$group` to reform the object.

```js
db.groups.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$members"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "members.userId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "usersLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$usersLookup"
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "members": {
        "user": "$usersLookup",
        "role": "$members.role"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "title": {
        $first: "$title"
      },
      "members": {
        "$push": "$members"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d1vjtOZ_63q)

Comment: You can unset the userId before the last group to get the same output structure OP provided  (it's an extra field): `{ "$unset": "members.userId" }`. https://mongoplayground.net/p/vTDM5KOsqsU

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the lookup is that if you insert the new field into an existing array it replaces that array, rather than adding the result to each object in the array. The Mongo docs provide a similar [example with `$lookup` and `$mergeObjects`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#use--lookup-with--mergeobjects). The key to using it effectively in your case is to `$unwind` the `members` first. And at the end, un-unwind (rewind? windup?) the objects and add the `members.user` to a single array.

```js
db.groups.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$members"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "members.userId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "members.user"
    }
  },
  {
    // convert list of one user to just user object
    "$set": {
      "members.user": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$members.user",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // your example output doesn't have this field
    "$unset": "members.userId"
  },
  {
    // un-unwind / rewind / windup
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "members": {
        "$push": "$members"
      },
      // add all remaining fields
      "title": {
        "$first": "$title"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xx8TtSR8nXG)

PS. Needs a more elegant solution to choose all the "other" fields in the final `$group`. Right now, "title" is the only one so it's fine but maybe something with a $project would work better for those cases.

For the curious, the difference between this and [Ray's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77539172/1431750) is that I lookup into the `members` object rather than at the root level. If there were many fields in each object of members, then this pipeline doesn't require `set`ting each of the other fields.